# Query de volumen filtrando datos por fecha en oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle-11g

necesito hacer una consulta en Oracle SQL que me permita saber el volumen de datos que usa una tabla dentro de la base de datos.
La query que tengo para ello es la siguiente

```
select segment_name table_name, 
SUM (BYTES) AS "[Bytes]",
SUM (BYTES) / 1024 AS "[Kb]",
SUM (BYTES) / (1024*1024) AS "[Mb]",
SUM (BYTES) / (1024*1024*1024) AS "[Gb]"
from user_extents 
where segment_type='TABLE' 
and segment_name = 'nombre_tabla'
group by segment_name
```

la cual me regresa perfectamente el peso de la tabla en bytes, kilos, megas y gigas. pero esta tabla dentro tiene una columna de fecha en la cual necesito filtrar porque necesito saber el peso que tienen los ultimos datos ngresados a la tabla. Una query normal que uso para filtrar por fecha es la siguiente.

```
SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla where fecha > '01/02/20' and fecha < '02/02/20'
```

Lo que no logro hacer es unir estas dos query, intente varias formas pero ni una funciona. ¿Alguno sabe como podria obtener el volumen de los datos que existen en el rango de fecha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calcular el tamaño exacto de un determinado conjunto de registros no es simple.

Oracle tiene una estructura de almacenamiento muy flexible y por ende compleja:
Tablespace < Segment < Extent < Oracle Data Block. Si lo imaginas como cajas pequeñas dentro de cajas grandes puedes saber el tamaño de las cajas mas no la del objeto que puede estar desarmado y distribuido en varias cajas pequeñas.

Por otro lado, Oracle tratará de optimizar de tal manera que un registro ocupe el menor espacio posible; dichas optimizaciones dependerán del tipo de dato y del valor en sí.

Podrías obtener una buena aproximación del tamaño con la función `vsize()`, la cual regresa el número de bytes de un valor, y sería algo como:

```
SELECT sum( vsize(columna1) + vsize(columna2) + vsize(columna3) )
  FROM nombre_tabla
  WHERE fecha > '01/02/20' 
    AND fecha < '02/02/20'
```

Otra aproximación más económica sería usando las *estadísticas*: de la tabla `user_tables` multiplicar el valor de la columna `avg_row_size` (tamaño promedio  de renglón) por el número de registros insertados.

```
SELECT avg_row_size
  FROM user_tables
  WHERE table_name = 'nombre_tabla'
```

Comment: Agradezco la respuesta, ambas me sirvieron pero la primera me a sido más efectiva para la necesidad que tengo ya que tienen que ser datos específicos. Gracias nuevamente

Comment: tengo una consulta, si la tabla no posee ni un timestamp o similar, es posible obtener cantidad de registros generados la ultima semana o algo similar? me di cuenta que no todas las tablas en la cual tengo que ejecutar la query poseen dicha información relacionada a una fecha. Por lo cual quedo nuevamente restrictivo.

Comment: Sin una referencia de tiempo no veo manera. En ciertos casos podrías deducir la fecha a partir de otra tabla.

Comment: Ok, eso me tenía, al menos podré hacerlo con más de la mitad de los datos. Gracias nuevamente

Comment: aprovecho de consultar, hay alguna forma de saber el peso que tienen los indices asociados a la información? no estaba considerando el peso que poseen ellos en la medición

Comment: En la tabla de segmentos, el nombre del segmento es el nombre del índice.